# How to hide sub-folder of scoped directory in Android 10 (Android Q) ? Using Media Store?

Tags: android, performance

Recently due to app behavior changes in android 10 i am using media store to save bitmap to storage.
But i have some pictures which i do not want users to see in gallery so i want to hide it on storage using **.(DOT)**

But when image is stored by my application its replacing ***.(DOT) with (SLASH)_.***

**E.G** 
`/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/.myFolder/_0.png` 
**Replaced with** 
`/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/_.myFolder/_0.png`

sample code

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap, @NonNull String name) throws IOException {
    OutputStream fos;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name + ".jpg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/.myFolder");
        Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        fos = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
    } 
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    Objects.requireNonNull(fos).close();
}
```

Comment: You better store temporary files not  with the media store but in getFilesDir() and such.

Comment: `How to hide sub-folder of scoped directory`. You are not using a 'scoped' directory at all.

Comment: @blackapps tried with DCIM same error facing

Comment: "But i have some temp files which i do not want users to see in gallery" -- do not put them in the `MediaStore`. As blackapps suggests, use `getFilesDir()`, `getCacheDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCachedir()`, and similar methods on `Context` to get a directory that you can use. Particularly for files described as "temp files", `getCacheDir()` would seem like a good choice.

Comment: ">But when image is stored by my application its replacing .(DOT) with (SLASH)_. " same issue !